# Syntax error, expected: ( paren_expr_list )

Tags: join, oracle-sqldeveloper

When I use this code, I get syntax error:

> expected: ( paren_expr_list )

When I hover my mouse over my code but I am able to run the code successfully.

```
    select  tA.userName      
    from tableA tA join
     tableB tB 
     on regexp_like(tA.userName, '^' || tB.name || '[0-9]{0,3}$')
    WHERE tB.ID = 'E044';
```

This is the image of the error message I receive:

[image]

Comment: Works fine in version 17.3